# git merge conflicts after not deploying for a while

Tags: git, github

so I have a local master and a github master and I just got a LONG list of merge conflicts after not deploying to my production branch for a while. I have been developing and committing away for about a month and then I decided it was finally time to deploy some new features that were added to the master.

My command to update the production master (on the server) is

```
git pull origin master
```

and I ended up getting a long list of conflicts similar to this...

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): blog/views.py deleted in 0ef3448d9cc01cf599ccaf16fc845dc49ce71ca7 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of blog/views.py left in tree.

CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in define/forms.py

CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in README.md
```

But I do not see why there should be any merge conflicts here. Should I be running a different command to update the production branch to the current HEAD of the github master?

EDIT:

For calirification, I do not make any changes to the production master, It hasn't been touched since the last `git pull` so shouldn't git just automatically merge in all the changes since the last commit?

Comment: Most likely other people made commits to the remote `master` branch since the last time you synched up.

Comment: absolutely not, I am the lone contributor

Comment: Have you rewritten your local history at some point?

Comment: I have done some local rebases to squash commits doing `git rebase -i HEAD~n`..if that is what you mean

Comment: You rewrote your local history.  Therefore, in general you will have to force push your branch.

Comment: right, but I am speaking about a pull here not a push. I force pushed to github and then did a pull from github on my production machine. Does your comment still apply?

Comment: Yes, it still applies.  When you rewrote your local history, you caused Git to not be able to just pull in changes from the remote.  The reason is that it can't figure out _where_ to apply those commits.

Comment: is there a command I could run that would make this pull happen smoothly?

Comment: In general, no, but usually this is handled the other way around.  Usually, if you rewrite history of your local branch, you would force push it out, which would eliminate the problem for pulling.